# Why does Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar not hide the action bar while android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar does

Tags: android, android-studio, android-styles

I recently tried learning Android development, however I am struggling to understand why a basic function does not seem to work.

When setting the parent of `AppTheme` to `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`, the title bar is not hidden like it is supposed to. Even manually adding

`<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`

to my `AppTheme` does not fix it. Curiously, setting the parent of `AppTheme` to `android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar` **does** work.

Why is this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I tried making a new project in Android studio to see if I can reproduce it myself and I can? 
For reference: I include kotlin support, target API 24 on phone and tablet only and start with 'Basic Activity'.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I kinda solved it myself. While I have no idea **why** things are this way (the *.NoActionBar themes not working and anything but AppCompat themes causing crashes), I *did* manage to hide the ActionBar.

`res/layout/activity_main.xml` has a section defining the ActionBar too, so just the  `android:visibility="gone"` property to `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` made it work.